# format openapi/swagger generated java source using maven plugin

Tags: maven, google-java-format

I've `openapi` plugin to autogenerate some java source code using `mustache` files as template.

I wish to format this code using google java style. I followed example at this link:
https://shankulk.com/format-your-java-code-with-google-java-format-5bf4de8756f5

This works but it formats the entire source code at `src/main/java` and `src/main/test`

I wish to format only generated code which is in `target/`
I tried using path as highlighted but it still formats the entire source code including auto generated code in `target/`

is there other standard maven plugin that can be used for this purpose or how can i set this up?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change autogenerated code which will be regenerated next build (as it should not be in your git repository)?

Comment: we see it sometimes and its quite unindented.

Comment: Changing `<sourceDirectory>` in the plugin configuration and running it after generating sources but before compilation does not do what you want?

Comment: No. it doesn't format anything. but if I make it src/main/java it formats all the java files.

Comment: Consider spending a bit of time with a debugger to understand why. Fixing the plug-in (or just find out how to use it correctly ) is probably the best long term solution.